# What are the pros and cons of using a Connection pool in a Java SE application?

Tags: java, oracle11g, connection-pooling

We are developing a Java SE application and I am using Hibernate to communicate with the Database. My database is Oracle 11g Express Edition. Up till now I have not used a connection pool in the application. But I have used c3p0 connection pool before but I never really had a good understanding of it.

What are the Pros and Cons of using c3p0 in a Java SE application? I can understand it's usefulness when it comes to a Java EE application but Java SE?

Here is my Configuration for Hibernate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">EP</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">EP</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

  <mapping class="app.model.User"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Making connections is expensive, and passing around pre-existing connections instead of making a new one for each request is a lot less expensive.  (You won't care if your db has such a light load it doesn't matter.)  Note that my answer has nothing to do with SE or EE, because the issue at hand has nothing to do with it either.

Comment: Yeah but is it necessary for Java SE applications to have multiple connections at a time?

Comment: Will you ever have more than 1 user at a time?

Comment: No... But does Hibernate Proxies demand Multiple connections?

Comment: It initially makes `min_size` connections, and makes up to `max_size` connections as more and more concurrent requests come in.  You can set these numbers to 1 and 1 if you like.

Comment: Will it improve Hibernate performance if I set the min_size to something like 3?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9008/discussion-between-duli-chan-and-bdares)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can understand it's usefulness when it comes to a Java EE application but Java SE?

The reason for using a connection pool in Java SE is *fundamentally the same* as in the Java EE case.  Openning and closing JDBC connections is relatively expensive, and connection pools allow you to reuse connections that the application openned previously.

(Obviously, if the Java SE application only ever needs to use one (or a small number) of JDBC connections, there is no pay-off in using a connection pool.  But the same would apply to a Java EE application with the same characteristics.)

---

> Yeah but is it necessary for Java SE applications to have multiple connections at a time?

1)  That entirely depends on the application, and what it does.

2)  A connection pool is also useful for an application that requires multiple connections serially ... but only ever one connection at a time.  Like for example if the connections are being created and closed in a 3rd-party library.

Comment: What do you think about the Hibernate Performance? Will having more connections improve Hibernate performance since Hibernate uses proxies for lazy loading?

Comment: That's a different issue.  Hibernate will decide to use more connections whether or not you use a connection pool.  Connection pooling is about connection lifecycles, not about how / whether multiple connections are used.

Comment: It strikes me (from your question and comments) that you are looking for a magic formula for improving Hibernate performance that excuses you from having to understand the technology.  Unfortunately, there isn't one.  There are various things that you can *try*, but there's no guarantee that they will help.  It really depends on the details of how your application uses Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks... but my real intention was to know whether SE applications using Hibernate will speed up with a connection pool. Since at our development department people close the connection once they query and open another connection to do another query...

Comment: @Duli-chan - my answer / comments address.  The answer is that **it depends on your application**.  Why don't you just try it??

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone ever realized that Java EE applications all run on the same Java SE JVM plus some addon libraries? This said, a Java EE application requires libraries that makes it work as a Java SE application, or in other words:
All EE containers are Java SE applications.

Before it was already noted that connection pooling is not related to SE or EE, it is more based on what the application is supposed to do.